# Ubuntu 22.04- 5GHZ Network not displaying with a TPLink T3U Archer wifi adapter

Tags: networking

I have recently [re: about a day ago as of writing] set up the drivers for my Archer T3U wifi adapter on Ubuntu 22.04. While it is able to recognize a 2.4ghz network, it is unable to pick up the local 5ghz network. Can supply information as needed.
Output of `iwlist freq`

```
lo        no frequency information.

enp4s0    no frequency information.

wlx34e894d7d356  32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Output of `nmcli device wifi list`

```
        xxxx  --                           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        xxxx  --                           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xxxx  --                           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  99      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
*       xxxx  My Koji 2                    Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  95      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        xxxx --                           Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2             
        xxxx DIRECT-A6-HP OfficeJet 8020  Infra  11    65 Mbit/s   57      ▂▄▆_  WPA2             
        xxxx  --                           Infra  36    0 Mbit/s    55      ▂▄__  WEP              
        xxxx  --                           Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  54      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxx SETUP-68CB                   Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxx  --                           Infra  48    65 Mbit/s   52      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxx  --                           Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA2             
        xxxx  --                           Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
~
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `iwlist freq` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact the BSSID with xxxx. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, I added that information to the post. Hope it helps!

Comment: It sees two 5 gHz access points, both hidden. To connect, follow the procedure to connect to a hidden network at the Network Manager icon. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAVj2.png

Comment: I note that one of the access points is encrypted with WEP. It is very insecure and, if you can, I'd change it immediately.

Comment: Inputting the information of the network I'm trying to connect to does nothing. I checked the MAC address of the 5g network, and it isn't in the list that `ncmli device wifi list` outputs.

Comment: I believe it would also be prudent to know that it manages to detect the network perfectly fine on Windows 10 (which I have Ubuntu dual-booted with)

Comment: Just for info: I had a similar problem on Windows. The cause was that,, the "WPA2 - Personal" encryption type was set by default to "ITK" instead of "AES". Once I changed it to AES, the 5GHz network turned visible :)

Answer (score 1):

The wireless frequencies which are available can vary depending on the regulatory domain (country) in which you are located. If the country code is set, for example, to CN, then different channels are available than set to US or JP.

I recommend that you set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Set `crda` to my country code, no change. Although, I believe `sudo iw reg get`'s output implied it was already set to that. I find it important to bring up that `/etc/default/crda` was empty when I first opened it. Is this normal?

Comment: As well, the lower segment indicates `country 99- DFS-UNSET`. Apparently this can be a driver problem?

Comment: UNSET means that you need to set it correctly. The file crda should read: `REGDOMAIN=` and then you edit the file to add your country code. Reboot.

Comment: Again, wrote into crda. No effect. I am also missing the crda file within sbin.

Comment: How about: /usr/lib/crda/regulatory.bin ? What is the driver you set up? 88x2bu? Or some other?

Comment: I have the 88xxbu driver set up. regulatory.bin is present.

Comment: Just installed the 88x2bu driver and used `modprobe`. Does not affect 5g connectivity.

Comment: Please see the comments about 5 gHz here: https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702 Does some other computer, phone or tablet tell you what channel the desired network is on?

Comment: The channel the network is on is 157, which should be in range? I noticed the driver you had linked was different from the one I had previously installed, so I installed that one and used modprobe. Unfortunately, it has had no noticeable effect.

Comment: Alright, I've figured out that my adapter and the drivers I have (and the only ones I've found for it) can only reach channel 153. So, I think I'm just gonna have to get a new adapter to fix it. Thank you for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1):

For kernel 5.11 or later

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential dkms git bc
git clone -b v5.13.1 https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU.git
cd RTL8812BU
make
sudo make install
sudo reboot
```

Credit: https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! I cleaned up your code a bit. I think it's safe to assume that bc is not required to achieve the desired result, Please confirm and edit accordingly. Cheers!